# Objective-C: Get Selected Value from UISwitch

Tags: objective-c, boolean, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

The following code is not behaving as I would expect. I think it may have to do with not handling `BOOL` and `NSNumber` correctly or possibly I am not storing a number as a user default correctly.  In any case, after getting a value from a `UISwitch` and trying to save it to user defaults, I am not getting value I thought I was saving.

```
NSNumber * on = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.onSwitch.on];
BOOL onBool = [on boolValue];
NSLog(@"onBool before save%d",onBool);//Logs as 0
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setBool:onBool forKey:@"on"];//
[prefs synchronize];
BOOL onDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"on"];
NSLog(@"value of on after save%d",onDefault);//logs as 1
```

Can anyone see where I have made the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to use appropriate **boolForKey** API, so instead of

```
BOOL onDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"on"];
```

try it like this:

```
BOOL onDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"on"];
```

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1416388-boolforkey?language=objc)

> `boolForKey:`
>   Returns the Boolean value associated with the specified key.

Comment: Yes, or objectForKey which returns the NSNumber, then send boolValue to that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I wanted to provide a little insight into what's going on here. You're setting a Boolean but asking for an Object. You're seeing `1` (`true`) because the method returns an object and by casting it to a boolean it will simply check for it's existence.